# How to list all releases of public repository with GitHub API V3

Tags: git, github, github-api

So as per the documentation https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#list-releases-for-a-repository

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/releases
```

should list all relases  , so

```
https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/releases
```

should list all [releases](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/releases) in JQuery project , but its not , why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that repository doesn't actually have any releases. It only has tags that GitHub is presenting in the releases page.

For a more clear example, see:

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/releases

Which has both releases and tags showing on that page, but the API only shows the releases:

https://api.github.com/repos/hashicorp/terraform/releases